# jumping from one calender to another

Tags: javascript

i  need to fetch the date i click on but by this code i am only getting what the current date is. how can i get the date which i click on.   i need to get any date which date i click on but i am unable to do that . i dont need the current date i need to fetch  the date i click on

```
dayClick: function() {

  var date =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'); 
  var dat = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date,"YYYY-MM-DD" ); 

  alert(" the date is "+dat);
  $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', 'dat');
},
```

Comment: Would you mind reducing your question to just one statement of your problem and what you want to achieve. It does not help to state it three times. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the first parameter of the [`dayClick`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayClick) event handler.

e.g.

```js
$('#calendar1').fullCalendar();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    var formattedDate = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log("the date is " + formattedDate);
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', formattedDate);

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id='calendar1'></div>
```